# Debug folder is automatically created on opening C# console application in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, console-application

I tried to create new project which is `C# console application` in visual studio 2008.

I have used Configuration manager to add x86 and x64.

And then selected Configuration as `Release` and Platform as `x64`.

Even though when I empty the contents of `bin` and `obj` folder after closing the project.

When I open the project debug folder is created in bin and obj folder.

How to avoid this ?

EDIT : If I build / rebuild after empytying the contents `bin` and `obj` folder, debug folder is not getting created. It is created only after the re opening the project.

EDIT 2 : Debug and release folders are created inside x64 and x86 apart from this I am seeing Release and Debug folder inside bin and obj. I am not sure which architecture this debug and release folder belongs to?

Comment: when you build the application debug folder would be created automatically

Comment: Is there any way to stop that ?

Comment: It is getting created only when I open the project. It is not getting created when I build or rebuild it.

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid this behaviour? If it is due to version control, then you can include the folders in the ignore functionality. I am assuming most IDE's have their own way of creating files and folders each time a project is opened, compiled or built.

Comment: Debug and release folders are created inside x64 and x86 apart from this I am seeing Release and Debug folder inside bin and obj. I am not sure which architecture this debug and release folder belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, removing Any CPU from target is enough to achieve this. Click on edit and then remove Any CPU from platforms. After which Only the active platform and target folder will be created